# AOSP cuttlefish: avoid booting in recovery mode loop

Tags: android, emulation, android-source

Using AOSP 14 and cuttlefish emulator, every time I do (adb reboot -> stop_cvd -> launch_cvd) virtual device always starts in recovery mode. How can I force to start in "normal" mode?

I already try deleting all temporary files and dirs generated by cuttlefish, powerwash_cvd, use "--resume=false" option...)